# Edit embed message to simple text discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to edit an embed message to a simple text message using discord.js and node.js. I already tried this but it don't work:

```js
const sentMessage = await message.channel.send({
  embed: { author: {name: 'Getting statistics for ' + message.author.username, icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/OWvklnj.gif'}}
})

[...]

sentMessage.edit("no statistics")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `message.edit()` alone won't work as it's only edits the content of the message. You can use the [suppressEmbeds() method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=suppressEmbeds) to remove the embed and then edit the content. The following should work:

```js
try {
  const sentMessage = await message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      author: {
        name: 'Getting statistics for ' + message.author.username,
        icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/OWvklnj.gif',
      },
    },
  });

  await sentMessage.suppressEmbeds();
  await sentMessage.edit('no statistics');
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```